# Vb.net - Display the mobile version of a website using WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Like the title says , i'm trying to display the mobile version of a website using a webbrowser , i don't know if it's possible or not but i have tried to add a header to my request but i wasn't lucky , it did nothing.
What i have tried:

```
Dim header As String = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0)"
browser.Navigate(TextBox1.Text, "_self", Nothing, header)
```

Comment: Try `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A5297c Safari/602.1` for the UA string.

Comment: In the webbrowser it display me an error page that says "Navigation to the web page was cancelled" with a refresh link , when i click on it it redirect me to the desktop (normal) version of the website.

Comment: What website are you trying to load?

Comment: For now : https://play.google.com/store/apps?hl=fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall placing m. in front of the URL but this could have been changed.
For example:

```
m.google.com
```

You could probably do something like this:

```
  dim MOB as string = "m."
```

then on the event:

```
 dim URL as string = textbox1.text
textbox1.text = MOB & URL
```

Comment: In my case , i try to access (most of the time) to play.google.com/store/apps , so an m. won't work

Comment: On some websites there is "mobile" path, such as example.com/mobile. It's rare but I hope it will help.